# 1146 Table doesn't exist on custom table name in Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

**Version CakePHP v3.4.7**

> QLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'DB.notifications' doesn't exist

I have my table name in spanish and I want to use my Model and my controller in English.

Into my NotificationsTable class I've already set the following line:

```
$this->table('notificaciones');
```

So I think that is sufficient with that and everything else I can use another name.

This is my NotificationsTable

```
class NotificationsTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('notificaciones');
        $this->primaryKey('notificaciones_id');

    }

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->add('notificaciones_id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
            ->allowEmpty('notificaciones_id', 'create');


        return $validator;
    }

    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['cola_id'], 'Colas'));

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

And this is my Controller:

```
class NotificationsController extends AppController
{

    public function index()
    {

        $this->paginate['contain'] = ['Colas'];
        $notifications = $this->paginate($this->Notifications);

        $this->set(compact('notifications'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['notifications']);
    }
}
```

I thought that just setting

```
$this->table('notificaciones');
```

it was enough and I could use another model and controller name and not the same name as my table.

Someone have an idea whats happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem!

It was on the namespace. I had:

```
namespace App\Model\Notification;
```

Instead of:

```
namespace App\Model\Table;
```

Nice coding!